# Django Models: __str__ with Foreign object's name

Tags: python, django, web

So I have a `Product` and `ProductImage` models. Each `Product` can have multiple `ProductImage` models. In the Django admin page, I want the product images to display the name of the product it's related to.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    product_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    description = models.TextField()



class ProductImage(models.Model):
    image_addr = models.FileField(upload_to='products/')
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        q = <*name of the product with the product_id*>
```

If a product image is that of a phone, say iPhone X, the image should display so. Now, the product images column only shows `ProductImage` objects. How do I solve this?
[image]

Comment: You shouldn't really call the foreign key field "product_id", as it gives access to the whole product object; call it just "product".

Comment: How does it give access to the whole product object?

Comment: I don't understand your question. `self.product_id` will be an instance of Product, not the id.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

> TIP: instead of `product_id` the field name could be `product`

if you change the name `product_id` to `product`, remember to product_id, in the following

```
def __str__(self):
    return "%s %s" % (self.product_id.name, self.product_id.id )
```

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work though. Spanning relationships only work for QuerySets I think.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should have a **unicode** method in each model so that you can view you data in more descriptive way. Your model should like this

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    product_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{}-{}".format(self.id, self.name)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    image_addr = models.FileField(upload_to='products/')
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{}".format(self.product_id)
```

Here i am suggesting **unicode** instead of **str** because if product name contains non-ascii character then **str** will raise error.